# MUIv4 Upgrade w/ TypeScript - Cannot spread props to TextField Properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui

Current Material-UI Version: `4.1.0`

I am having issues spreading props to an abstracted `<TextField />` component I've created.

Here is the code:

`PasswordInput.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react'
import TextField, { Props as TextFieldProps } from 'src/TextField'

type Props = TextFieldProps & {
  hideHelperText?: boolean;
};

class PasswordInput extends React.Component<Props> {
  onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    /** do stuff */
  };

  render() {
    const {
      hideHelperText,
      classes,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TextField
          /** errors out here */
          /*
            Type 'HideShowText | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.
            Type 'HideShowText' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLDivElement':
            align, addEventListener, removeEventListener, accessKey, and 238 more
          */
          {...rest}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        {!hideHelperText && 'hello world'}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default PasswordInput;
```

`TextField.tsx`

```
import TextField, {
  StandardTextFieldProps as TextFieldProps
} from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

type ClassNames =
  | 'root'

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {},
  });

interface BaseProps {
  tooltipText?: string;
  dataAttrs?: Record<string, any>
}

export type Props = BaseProps & TextFieldProps

type CombinedProps = Props &
  WithStyles<ClassNames>;

class MyTextField extends React.Component<CombinedProps> {
  render() {
    const {
      children,
      tooltipText,
      dataAttrs,
      /** everything else that goes on the root */
      ...textFieldProps
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div
      >
        <TextField
          {...textFieldProps}
          {...dataAttrs}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </TextField>
        {tooltipText && <HelpIcon text={tooltipText} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styled = withStyles(styles);

export default compose<CombinedProps, Props>(
  styled
)(MyTextField);
```

It's bombing with the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ tooltipText: string | undefined; value: string | undefined; onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void; fullWidth: true; required: boolean | undefined; errorText?: string | undefined; ... 282 more ...; innerRef?: ((instance: any) => void) | ... 2 more ... | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicClassAttributes<HideShowText>'.
  Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
    Type '((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HideShowText | null) => void) | RefObject<HideShowText> | null | undefined'.
      Type '(instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HideShowText | null) => void) | RefObject<HideShowText> | null | undefined'.
        Type '(instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: HideShowText | null) => void'.
          Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
            Type 'PasswordInput | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.
              Type 'PasswordInput' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLDivElement': align, addEventListener, removeEventListener, accessKey, and 238 more.
```

It appears that the `...rest` in the PasswordInput should be equal to the `StandardTextFieldProps` but for some reason I'm getting errors for my component not being an `HTMLDivElement`?

Let me know if I can provide more detail. As far as I can tell, this is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this exact error yesterday. I'm doing the same type union in other places, such as with `SelectProps`, without an issue, but `TextFieldProps` is problematic on multiple properties and `StandardTextFieldProps` on just `ref`. Therefore, as a temporary measure you could declare:

```
export type MyTextFieldProps = Omit< StandardTextFieldProps, 'ref' > & { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

@flatline. Thanks for the suggestion. I also had a working solution in changing how exporting was typed. To be honest, I'm not exactly sure why this works but it does. Take note of the last lines in each file:

```
TextField.tsx
```

```
import TextField, {
  StandardTextFieldProps as TextFieldProps
} from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

type ClassNames =
  | 'root'

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {},
  });

interface BaseProps {
  tooltipText?: string;
  dataAttrs?: Record<string, any>
}

export type Props = BaseProps & TextFieldProps

type CombinedProps = Props &
  WithStyles<ClassNames>;

class MyTextField extends React.Component<CombinedProps> {
  render() {
    const {
      children,
      tooltipText,
      dataAttrs,
      /** everything else that goes on the root */
      ...textFieldProps
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div
      >
        <TextField
          {...textFieldProps}
          {...dataAttrs}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </TextField>
        {tooltipText && <HelpIcon text={tooltipText} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styled = withStyles(styles);

export default compose<CombinedProps, Props>(
  styled
)(MyTextField) as s React.ComponentType<Props>;;
```

```
PasswordInput.tsx
```

```
import * as React from 'react'
import TextField, { Props as TextFieldProps } from 'src/TextField'

type Props = TextFieldProps & {
  hideHelperText?: boolean;
};

class PasswordInput extends React.Component<Props> {
  onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    /** do stuff */
  };

  render() {
    const {
      hideHelperText,
      classes,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <TextField
          /** errors out here */
          /*
            Type 'HideShowText | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.
            Type 'HideShowText' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLDivElement':
            align, addEventListener, removeEventListener, accessKey, and 238 more
          */
          {...rest}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        {!hideHelperText && 'hello world'}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default PasswordInput as React.ComponentType<Props>;;
```